# mysql count unique row values

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

`TABLE quotation`

```
id  clientid
1   25
2   25
3   25
4   25
5   26
```

How can I query how many different clients exist in `TABLE quotation`? I don't want duplicate entries to be counted more than once.

I need the answer to be `2`, in 1 row, because the only non-duplicated entries are (`25`, `26`).

Comment: Your title is misleading: you are not counting the duplicate rows, but the unique number of rows. Counting duplicate rows would return "4" since there are 4 rows which have the same value for clientid.

Comment: Proposed an edit to the question title/text, since this question is currently the top google hit for "mysql count duplicate entries".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
select count(distinct clientid) from quotation
```

[read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

Answer (score 4):

I find a way out

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotation GROUP BY
clientid) t1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the total number of unique entries this will return a number in column count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotation GROUP BY clientid having count(*) > 1) t1
```

If you want to count the total number of entries with duplicate rows then use the following mysql.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotation GROUP BY clientid having count(*) >= 2) t1
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following on a MySQL 5.x database.

id is an integer and clientid is an integer. I populated with two rows:

```
id  clientid
1   25
2   25
```

This SQL query will print the rows that have exactly 2 elements:

```
select * from test1 group by clientid having count(*) = 2;
```

If you want 2 or more elements, replace `= 2` in the example above with `>= 2`.

```
select * from test1 group by clientid having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT clientid, COUNT(clientid) FROM quotation 
GROUP BY clientid
```

Comment: This does not get the total count for client like: 
"select count(distinct clientid) from quotation"

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT clientid) as Unique_Client FROM quotation;
```

The resulted output is 2 as per the requirement, because the unique client ID  are 25 and 26