# Select all but ignore duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have a mysql table in which one field will hold duplicates.  I am trying to select all but ignore all rows where a duplicate exists in this field.

So if for example I have 10 rows in total, and 3 of them have duplicates I like to return 8 rows.  The 7 that were unique and 1 of the 3 duplicates.

I have tried distinct and group by without success.  They ignore all 3 duplicates.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM directory_listings
GROUP BY url
WHERE status = 'approved'
ORDER BY site_name ASC
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

and

```
SELECT * DISTINCT url
FROM directory_listings
WHERE status = 'approved'
ORDER BY site_name ASC
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

Comment: Why do you want to return 1 of the duplicates?

Comment: I need to return one of the duplicates for completeness.  If I have records a, b, b, c, d then I want to return a, b, c, d

Comment: @Ruf1 Are all columns the same value for the duplicates, or is it just a duplicate in a certain column?

Comment: @AlexW - it's just the column 'url' where there could be a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> @AlexW - it's just the column 'url' where there could be a duplicate – Ruf1 9 mins ago

Then your first query will work if you correct the syntax - `GROUP BY` must follow `WHERE` (per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT *
FROM directory_listings
WHERE status = 'approved'
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY site_name ASC
```

[Here's an example of a working query in SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac2f8/2)

Comment: i also need a similar query to ascertain the number of unique rows. would this be correct or do I use group: "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT url) FROM directory_listings WHERE status = 'approved'"

Comment: That should work fine; see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4131937/2359271. If you used `GROUP BY` you would be getting separate counts for each group (which can be useful to find duplicates, as in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac2f8/10)!)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for `SELECT DISTINCT` is wrong:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Also, the only reason `GROUP BY` wouldn't work to eliminate duplicates is if the `WHERE` clause is disqualifying some of the rows (i.e. they are not duplicates in terms of both `status` and `url`).

Comment: +1 for a good point about the `WHERE` clause. IMO this answer would be much improved by giving the correct syntax explicitly instead of only linking the docs. I know when I was starting out with SQL, I found the syntax descriptions in the docs very confusing; and external links can be unstable.